# Where can I find an external extension keypad?

Tags: keyboard

I want to add an additional grid of 6x4 keys that can be mapped to any function. Where can I find such a product?

Comment: I googled , I couldn't find anything related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They exist, but it looks like a lot of them are for industrial/commercial use, and all the ones I can find are pretty expensive ([check out this manufacturer's website](http://www.fentek-ind.com/keypad.htm)).

It would probably be cheaper and easier to get a [programmable gaming keyboard.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100008650+600009669&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=63&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=)

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest thing I found. It comes with 25 keys, so you could build a quick 4x6 matrix, or do something else if you wanted to.

http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/keyboards-mice/77ba/

[image]

Comment: +1 - That's cool! (but expensive)

Answer (score 0):

From the makers of the [Optimus Maximus keyboard](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/optimus/). Unfortunately the [Optimus AUX](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/optimus-aux/) is only a prototype.

[image]

Each key has a little screen 48 x 48 pixels that can display at 10 frames per second.

I would guesstimate that the price of this would be around US$600-800 if it were to be made available.

A three key version has been available, but is sold out with no indication of future availability.

Comment: That looks awesome! It is, however, way outside my price range.